# jdk1.7 Double.parseDouble become slow in multithread condition with large calculate

Tags: jdk1.7

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=2936

jdk1.7 Double.parseDouble() become very slow in multiThread condition, it's a bug in jdk1.7 and fix in jdk1.8

Answer (score 0):

upgrade jdk1.7 to jdk1.8 to solve this problem, because in jdk1.7 Double.parseDouble() will cause lock competition